# Java: How to use a pair of keys for HashMap

Tags: java, sql, dictionary, hashmap

From a sql database, I am reading a table with 2 fields: appName, user. So I may see:

```
+-------------+
| appA | John |
+-------------+
| appB | Mary |
+-------------+
| appC | Tom  |
+-------------+
| appA | John |
+-------------+
| appA | Mary |
+-------------+
```

Each of these records is stored as an object of a AppClass with appName and user.
Now, i want to list how many times the apps were run by different users. So :

```
+-----------------+
| appA | John | 2 |
+-----------------+
| appA | Mary | 1 | 
+-----------------+
| appB | Mary | 1 |  
+-----------------+
| appC | Tom  | 1 | 
+-----------------+
```

Is it possible do the counting with a HashMap with 2 keys?

Comment: Why not do the group and sum in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a structure like the following:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>
       ^           ^       ^
       appName    user    count
```

But it'd be much easier if you just fetch the aggregated data directly from the database:

```
SELECT appName, user, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY appName, user;
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, create an `AppUser` class that includes the appName and the user. Override `hashCode()` and `equals()` for your `AppUser` class.

You can then use a:

```
Map<AppUser, Integer> map;
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Create a pair that implements `hashCode()` and `equals()` properly and use that as the key type.  If you're using a library like apache commons you can probably find a pair or tuple class there, but otherwise the below will work.

Don't overdo generic pairs though.  It's fine to define a key class to handle the relationship between a pair of items in a collection, but many people have principled objections to wide use of pair classes in Java.

```
public final class PairKey<A, B> {
  public final A a;
  public final B b;

  private PairKey(A a, B b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }

  public static <A, B> PairKey<A, B> make(A a, B b) { return new PairKey<A, B>(a, b); }

  public int hashCode() {
    return (a != null ? a.hashCode() : 0) + 31 * (b != null ? b.hashCode() : 0);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || o.getClass() != this.getClass()) { return false; }
    PairKey that = (PairKey) o;
    return (a == null ? that.a == null : a.equals(that.a))
        && (b == null ? that.b == null : b.equals(that.b));
  }
}
```

and then to put an entry for a and b into the map, just do

```
myMap.put(new PairKey(a, b), value)
```

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
Map<String, Integer> appUserToCountMap
```

use `appA:John` as key for example

Comment: This is quite a dangerous pattern for anything but the most limited cases.

Comment: Everybody's happy, right until an app named "app1:v2.1" shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using Commons Collections' Bag. See [`Bag.getCount(key)`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html#getCount%28java.lang.Object%29)