# Android SparseArray<SparseArray<Object>> initialization

Tags: android, initialization, sparse-array, multikey

I have to implement the classification of somehting like Hashmap with two keys and a value, let's say `Hashmap<K1, K2, V>`, where the two keys are integers and the value is a generic MyObject defined by me.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768963/multiple-keys-to-single-value-map-java), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032961/java-how-to-use-a-pair-of-keys-for-hashmap) post, and I also know that guava project offers [the table interface](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html), but I don't want to use external libraries (if not strictly necessary) to keep my project smaller as possible. 
So I decided to use SparseArrays: I thought that this was the better choice because my keys are int and are not necessarily starting from zero and increasing.

I do this initializing:

```
SparseArray<SparseArray<MyObject>> myObjectSparseArray = new SparseArray<SparseArray<MyObject>>();
```

Now let's go to the point. Can I do this kind of operation:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObjectSparseArray.get(3).put(2,myObject);
```

or should I do something like:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObjectSparseArray.put(3, new SparseArray<MyObject>());
myObjectSparseArray.get(3).put(2,myObject)
```

In other words: Do I initialize both SparseArrays with this single line?

```
SparseArray<SparseArray<MyObject>> myObjectSparseArray = new SparseArray<SparseArray<MyObject>>()
```

Do you think there are better implementations for my case?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two keys and one value, I would just use a normal `HashMap` or `SparseArray` and will combine those two keys into one value.
Let's say you have one key which is `String` and one which is `Long` so your map key will be:
`(strKey + longKey).hashCode()`. You can use it as `Integer` and save it into `SparseArray` or as `String` and use `HashMap`.

Comment: both of the keys are int, the only alternative solution I thought was using normal 'Hashmap' or 'SparseArray' and use as a key a string composed by the two int:


    int key1 = 3;
    int key2 = 2;
    
    String Key = "key1: " + key1 + " key: " + key2;

But I found it a bit tricky..

Comment: Why do you think it's tricky? `String key = key1 + key2` (In our case the key String should be "32"), you can use `SparseArray` by doing `key.hashCode()` or `HashMap` using the `String` itslef.

Answer (score 0):

Having tow nested `SparseArray` is against the purpose of having `SparseArray` in the first place since you will allocate a new `SparseArray` for each unique first key in your `key` pairs.

A good solution for that would be by using hashmap and use a key object that takes two int values (**Point** for example) or an object that you define that simply holds two keys.